# Background image with soft keyboard

Tags: android

Cтавлю картинку на фон, всё ок пока не вызываю клавиатуру, если её вызвать то картинку сжимает, кто знает как решить проблему?

[image: чат без клавиатуры, всё ок]

[image: с клавиатурой]

Comment: Покажите разметку xml, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Картинка у вас скорей всего в ImageView. ПОбробуйте поменять scaleType или установите ее на фон для родительского layout